# Why can't I printf() to stdout in C without using fflush()?

Tags: c

I recently started programming in C and something I can't seem to get my head around is the way stdout prints to screen.

When I added all my statements in the main() function and used the printf() function everything worked well, all the printf() statements were able to print to stdout.

```
From Main.c
...
#include "HeaderFile.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
 ...
 printf("%c\n", testChar);
 return 0;/*End of execution. Returns 0 value and ends gracefully*/
}
...
```

But when I started to modularize my code in different functions, I realised that I have to insert the fflush(stdout) function at the end of each printf() function in order for the print function to print out to stdout:

```
From ReadFile.c
...
#include "HeaderFile.h"
void readFileFunction(char* file){
 ...
 printf("%c\n", testChar);
 fflush(stdout);
 ...
}
...
```

Header file:

```
 /*This is the header file used by the Linked list program.*/
/*This is the header file used by the Linked list program.*/
#ifndef HEADERFILE_H   /* Include guard */
#define HEADERFILE_H

#include <stdio.h> /*including the stdio file inside the Main.c file. stdio.h is a header file, where this and other similar functions are defined.*/
#include <string.h>/*including the string file inside the Main.c file. string.h is a header file, where this and other similar functions are defined.*/
#include <time.h>/*including the time file inside the Main.c file. time.h is a header file, where this and other similar functions are defined.*/
#include <stdint.h>/*including the stdint file inside the Main.c file. stdint.h is a header file, where this and other similar functions are defined.*/
#include <stdlib.h>/*including the stdlib file inside the Main.c file. stdlib.h is a header file, where this and other similar functions are defined.*/
#include <errno.h> /*including the errno file inside the Main.c file. errno.h is a header file, where this and other similar functions are defined.*/
#include <regex.h>

extern const char errorString[]; /*A string of characters. Indicates an error message when the program in-counters a problem during execution.*/   

/*String constants used to match user input with a specific function.*/
extern const char *string1;
extern const char *string2;
extern const char *string3;
extern const char *string4;
extern const char *string5;
extern const char *string6;
extern const char *string7;
extern const char *string8;
extern const char *string9;

/*Node structure with character value and the next node.*/
typedef struct node {
    char value;
    char type;
    struct node * next;
} nodeStruct;

/*function prototypes for every function being used in the code.*/
int removeChar(nodeStruct ** head, char value);
void readFileInit(char* file);
void readFileFunction(char *file);
void printList(nodeStruct * head) ;
void push(nodeStruct ** head, char value) ;
char tail(nodeStruct * head) ;
char head(nodeStruct * head) ;
int length(nodeStruct * head) ;
int pop(nodeStruct ** head) ;
int regularExpr (const char *patt, char *str) ;
void append(nodeStruct ** head, char value) ;
int insertAfter(nodeStruct ** head, char value, char value2) ;
int insertBefore(nodeStruct ** head, char value, char value2) ;

#endif // HEADERFILE_H
```

Would you please explain in details why this sudden difference?

Comment: Don't use parentheses for `return`, they are not needed and it makes `return` look as if it were a function. Also, you need to show more. Because what you just posted could not possibly be the problem, the `'\n'` character should cause the buffer to be flushed.

Comment: Do you mean the output isn't shown *immediately* (That's okay, standard output may be buffered.) or isn't shown *at all*, even after program exit?

Comment: Following @iharob please do not correct your question in response to comments, unless it helps to clarify the question. In this case, it doesn't. Just post the exact code in question.

Comment: It might be implementation specific. What operating system, what file system, what C standard library, compiler, and compilation options are you using? Is *stdout* a pseudo terminal (see [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)...) or a pipe?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added the extra code. @WeatherVane I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...); then use your debugger (`gdb`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function prototype for `fflush` is this:

```
int fflush ( FILE * stream );
```

It flushes the file pointer to the stream ensuring its written.

Depending on the environment where the code is executing on, the `stdout` in this case could well be buffered, implying that it does not get written straight away. `fflush` alleviates that and ensures it is flushed out.

Another thing, the kernel could be under a load at the point of execution thus delaying the printing to the console or terminal in this case, in which case, ending up judiciously sprinkling `fflush` all over the place.

It might help to enclose a SCCE example as looking at the OP's question, it is not easy to discriminate as to why, more of rather what is happening.

**Edit:**

The code can specify that the output is automatically written without buffering by including this snippet

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

It would be good practice, to save the state of buffer control at the start, switch off the buffering, and at end of code execution restore the buffer control.

Comment: Notice that disabling buffering would probably slow down the output a big lot. Buffering is *useful* most of the time!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Indeed, I left that in there to explain the mystery about buffering, it is definitely an optional thing, but for the impatient... :)